# Xamarin froms Tabbar load page Dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, tabbar

We are using xamrin from to build an mobile, app our scenario is to navigate from side menu to tab bar there we need set the current page of tabbar dynamically,

Here is our code,

```
 public Task NavigateToMyCartPage()
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    this.CurrentPage = this.Children[2];
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    this.CurrentPage = this.Children[2];
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

In iOS navigation is working expect. In android we are facing issue, like its not navigating to the 3rd page. its navigating to 1st page.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you post where you are calling `NavigateToMyCartPage()` please? Where you call it may make a difference.

Comment: we have public instance for tabbar and         public static MainTabbarPage mainTabbarPage;
one one page we are calling the mainTabbarPage.NavigateToMyCartPage();

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the currentpage on UI thread:

```
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        // your code here
        this.CurrentPage = this.Children[2];
    });
```

Comment: Nick Kovalsky,  No luck with this